# How do I profile a Codeigniter Web App with XDebug?

Tags: linux, apache, codeigniter, xdebug

I'm running XDebug on Linux CentOS.  I want to profile pages on a web app built with CodeIgniter, served by Apache.

XDebug is enabled in php.ini with the following settings:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp/xdebug
```

Everything works fine when I trigger php scripts from the command line, and XDebug profile logs are written to /tmp/xdebug, as expected.  When I load a url from the web app through the browser, XDebug does not create any profile log files.

Has anyone gotten XDebug to work with Codeigniter?  From what I can tell, I should not have to trigger XDebug profiling via GET in the url because profiler_enable is turned on for all php scripts, although I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache needed to have write permissions on the /tmp/xdebug folder.

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /tmp/xdebug
```

XDebug can profile Codeigniter page loads from a browser now.

Thanks @J. Bruni.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the issue is not related to CodeIgniter... It seems you may have multiple `php.ini` files...

In my Ubuntu installation, I have several sub-directories inside `/etc/php5` directory: `cgi`, `cli`, `fpm`, etc. Each one of these has a `php.ini` file inside it, which is specific to a single "mode".

In other words: PHP may have several different `php.ini` files... one for `CLI` (command-line), other for `CGI`, and so on...

Maybe the xdebug configuration lines you pasted above are not in the `php.ini` file used when you access PHP scripts from the browser. Maybe you added these lines to `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` instead of `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini` (or another... in my setup, it is `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`, because I use php-fpm)

Comment: Just found at xdebug documentation. I think you should try this simple test: "Write a PHP page that calls 'phpinfo()' Load it in a browser and look for the info on the Xdebug module. If you see it next to the Zend logo, you have been successful!"

Comment: Everything looks good when I do that.  Xdebug is loading and all it's settings are outputted with phpinfo().

Comment: So, the problem is not with `php.ini`... have you tried `phpinfo()` inside a CodeIgniter controller? (Just to check if xdebug is still there...)

Comment: A guy in Windows solved his problem changing the log file name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076743/xdebug-profiler-does-not-working  -  Also, the web server Apache must have permission to write in the profiler_output_dir...

Comment: apache needed write permissions.  now it's profiling codeigniter page loads through the browser.  damn.  how many times will that be my problem.  haha.  thank you for your help.